# Run node js on apache2 ssl enabled subdomain hosted on aws

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, apache2, subdomain, subdirectory

I have set up the the ssl enabled subdomain and installed the node js. Node js runs perfectly fine on the port number but I want to exclude port number from the subdomain. I have done ProxyPass and ProxyReverse settings in the virtual host as well as in the 000-default.conf file for port 80 and 443.

Due to ssl my http requests are redirecting to https:// and on https:// enabled subdomain I'm only able to see directory listing of node js.

On my main domain php is running due to which PORT 80 is reserved. My subdomain appthumbnail.example.com:3000 works but I need to do it with https://appthumbnail.example.com.

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Please provide your config for Apache.

Comment: <VirtualHost  *:80>
    ServerName appthumbnail.example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/fbpreviewgenerator
    ProxyRequests off

    <Proxy *>
             Require all granted
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass /fbpreviewgenerator http://*.example.com:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse /fbpreviewgenerator http://*.example.com:3000/
    ProxyPreserveHost on
</VirtualHost>

Comment: <VirtualHost *:443> 
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/fbpreviewgenerator
  ServerName appthumbnail.example.com
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/certs/example.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/keysudo/example.key
  SSLUseStapling on
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost on
  ProxyPass /fbpreviewgenerator http://*.example.com:3000/fbpreviewgenerator
  ProxyPassReverse /fbpreviewgenerator http://*.example.com:3000/fbpreviewgenerator

  SSLProxyEngine on 
  SSLProxyVerify none

</VirtualHost>